# New processes can't be run using session management, version 6.0 Blue Prism

Tags: blueprism

In my control room there are 2 resources that have each 1 item pending. However setting all filters to "All" doesn't show any unresolved sessions.

The first thing I thought was maybe a schedule that was planned in the future but the Timetable seems to be empty too. Any ideas to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, the trick was to close the connection and restart it. This seemed to clear the pending session.

Comment: This is likely the manifestation of a bug that's been around since at least v5. You've hit the nail on the head that this is likely the only way to effectively clear these "ghost" sessions.